# RecyclerView Set Alpha To Selected Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a horizontal RecyclerView which has all items alpha set to 0.5 in the XML, so that I can set the alpha to 1f when an item is selected however I have implemented an `onItemClick` in onCreate of MainActivity and not in `public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)`. Below is the code for `onItemClick`

```
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

        ImageView ivPreview;
        ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.ivPreview);
        ivPreview.setAlpha(1f); //<-- this should set to selected item

        url_abs_fileName = adapter_hgv_preview.getItem(position);

        vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter_Catalogue(this, strArr_MainImage);
        vp.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
        vp.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
```

How do I set this `ivPreview.setAlpha(1f);` only on the selected item? (Currently it sets to first item no matter which item is clicked)

Comment: you should not create and assign a new adapter

Comment: @TimCastelijns that's for my ViewPager don't worry about that (it just changes the image on the ViewPager selected from the RecyclerViewer preview), this works fine

Comment: ok anyway what is your question

Comment: ivPreview.setAlpha(1f); How to set this alpha on selected item of RecyclerViewer?

Comment: Use view.findViewById instead

Comment: You need to access the ImageView from the View passed to you, not globally.

Comment: @TimCastelijns using view.findViewById works however how can I reset all views back to 0.5 since they remain "highlighted" (1f) after item click on another item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the clicked view already.

```
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

        //ImageView ivPreview;
        //ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.ivPreview);
        //ivPreview.setAlpha(1f); //<-- this should set to selected item

        //reset all view state in recyclerview
         myAdapter.notifyDataSetchanged();
         recyclerView.invalidate(); 

        //set opacity of current view
         view.setAlpha(1f);

         //set opacity of child if it is wrapped around a parent element or view group
         View childView = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPreview);
         childView.setAlpha(1f);

        ...
```

**Edit**

An alternative option would be to save the selected position to preference, redraw the recyclerview onItem click then make use of saved position when initialize adapter views.

```
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

        //Initialize preference: You may want to take this outside
        SharedPreference prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreference.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

       //Save position to preference to retrieve later            
       editor.putInt("position",position).apply();

        //reset all view state in recyclerview
         myAdapter.notifyDataSetchanged();
         recyclerView.invalidate(); 

        //no need of setting alpha here
        ...
```

Then in your adapter onBindViewHolder

```
        //Initialize preference: You may want to take this outside
        SharedPreference prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        //reset view to initial state
        holder.ivPreview.setAlpha(0.5f);
        //get last selected view
        if(prefs.getInt("position",-2) == position)
        holder.ivPreview.setAlpha(1f);
```

Comment: views that have been clicked remain "highlighted" (1f), how can I reset all these views to 0.5f before applying 1f to selected item so that only one item remains highlighted?

Comment: the reset views code is not resetting the views, they still remain highlighted

Comment: Make sure to call `holder.ivPreview.setAlpha(0.5f);` inside your adapter onBindViewHolder

Comment: when I do that all items are NOT highlighted and remain so even after click events

Comment: added alternative option using preference check update